# Replace CSS attribute using Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, css, scripting

I have following code which have a css class called "formErrorContent"

```
var promptContent = $('<div>').addClass("formErrorContent").
                                  html(promptText).appendTo(prompt);
```

Before addiing the class as per the above code. I need to replace the width attribute 
with some other values like this

```
   $("#formErrorContent").attr("WIDTH","13");
```

But the above line is not working and not setting the width attibute to 13 in the css class "formErrorContent"

Please help me on this ... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('<div/>', {
  'class': "formErrorContent",
   width: '13px',
   text: promptText
}).appendTo(prompt);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Urr2c/1/

Comment: one more help i need to make this 13 as a variable ...how to do that?

Comment: @PeteEngineer You are welcome, you can define a variable and replace `13px` with that variable.

Comment: thats giving an error like </Br> is showing at the end when i did like below          var promptWidth = (promptText.length * 5) - (promptText.length/2) + "px;";
        
            var promptContent = $('<div/>', { 'class': "formErrorContent", style: 'width:' + promptWidth , text: promptText}).appendTo(prompt);

Comment: @PeteEngineer  You should not use `+` there, try removing that. Note that I have updated the code using `width` as a property, you can use that property.

Answer (score 2):

Use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) and change the selector to class, because you set it as class:

```
var promptContent = $('<div>').addClass("formErrorContent").html(promptText).appendTo(prompt);
$(".formErrorContent").css("width","13px");
```

Comment: NOpe i am unable to see a difference

Comment: $(".formErrorContent").css("WIDTH",promptWidth);

Answer (score 1):

you are adding a **class** but are referring to an **id**. try

```
$(".formErrorContent").css("width","13");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like

```
$('#selector_id').css("width","100");
```

Comment: It works...!!check whether your selector id will be "selector_id" and also try $("#selector_id").css("width",100)....(may be)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
$("#selector_id").width(100);
```

may hope it works directly